# Error with Structs

Tags: c++, codeblocks, header-files

I am beginning to teach myself C++ and have come across an error for which I believe is quite simple but not catching it. I created the following header file named EmployeeT.h

```
#ifndef EMPLOYEET_H_INCLUDED
#define EMPLOYEET_H_INCLUDED

typedef struct
{
    char firstInitial;
    char middleInitial;
    char lastInitial;
    int employeeNumber;
    int salary;
} EmployeeT

#endif // EMPLOYEET_H_INCLUDED
```

with the main as

```
#include <iostream>
#inclide <Employee.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    EmployeeT anEmployee;
    anEmployee.firstInitial = 'M';
    anEmployee.middleInitial = 'R';
    anEmployee.lastInitial = 'G';
    anEmployee.employeeNumber = 42;
    anEmployee.salary = 80000;
    cout << "Employee: " << anEmployee.firstInitial <<
                            anEmployee.middleInitial <<
                            anEmployee.lastInitial << endl;
    cout << "Number: " << anEmployee.employeeNumber << endl;
    cout << "Salary: " << anEmployee.salary <<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You haven't mentioned the error. Also, there's absolutely no need for `typedef struct {} blah;` in C++. Just use `struct blah{};`. C++ offers much more functionality than plain C structs as well, such as constructors, which could be of use here, and operator overloading, which would be useful to print it, but the latter might be a bit advanced for what you need right now.

Comment: Besides the missing semicolon *incliding* `EmployeeT.h` and `Employee.h` would be different files.

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Press tell us what they are.

Comment: `typedef struct { ... } Name;` is vestigial, early, C. Just write `struct Name { ... };` instead.

Answer (score 9):

You missed semicolon:

```
 typedef struct
 {
     char firstInitial;
     char middleInitial;
     char lastInitial;
     int employeeNumber;
     int salary;
 } EmployeeT;
           //^^Must not miss this ;
```

Meanwhile:

```
 #inclide <Employee.h>
    //^^typo
```

should be:

```
#include "Employee.h"
```

Last point: you may initialize your struct as follows:

```
anEmployee = {'M','R','G',42, 80000}; 
             //It will assign values to field in automatic way
```

If you are curious, you may also take a look at `uniform initialization` which is introduced since C++11.

Answer (score 4):

In main don't you want to `#include "EmployeeT.h"` instead of `#include <Employee.h>`?